# ASP.NET : generate ListBoxItems from values in database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, linq, selectlistitem

I want to populate a listbox, so I have to define an array of ListBoxItem.
The data is stored in a database.

This is my original method:

```
public IEnumerable<String> GiveStudentsNormalAsString(int lesson, int class)
    {
        Lesson l = giveLesson(lesson);
        Class c = GiveClass(l, class);
        return (from s in c.Students
                orderby s.Name, s.FirstName
                select s.Name);
    }
```

So "Class" contains a List of Students (a navigational property).
What I want to do is not returning an IEnumerable of Strings, but an IEnumerable of SelectListItems.

I started already:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GiveStudentsNormalAsString(int lesson, int class)
    {
        Lesson l = giveLesson(lesson);
        Class c = GiveClass(l, class);
        return .Select(student => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = ...
            Value = ...
        };
    }
```

But what do I have to write as Text and Value? for example, I want the Student Number act as Value, how can I do that?

Here's my edmx:
EDMX[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbD6b.png)

Answer (score 0):

You just refer to the `student` variable when building the `SelectListItem`:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GiveStudentsNormalAsString(int lesson, int class)
{
    Lesson l = giveLesson(lesson);
    Class c = GiveClass(l, class);
    return c.Students.Select(student => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = student.Name,
        Value = student.Number.ToString()
    });
}
```

Of course it can also be written using the LINQ syntax, if you prefer so:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GiveStudentsNormalAsString(int lesson, int class)
{
    Lesson l = giveLesson(lesson);
    Class c = GiveClass(l, class);
    return (from student in c.Students
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = student.Name,
                Value = student.Number.ToString()
            });
}
```

Comment: But I have a question: when I enter Value = student.StudentID, it gives me an error saying that it cannot convert from int to string...

Comment: @Laurent That's because `SelectListItem.Value` is `string`, so you have to convert `student.StudentID` to string first. I updated the code accordingly.